# Catastophe inhibitor against WMD's

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, energy

I want to have a catastrophe inhibitor (CatIn from now on) that reduces the effects of WMDs like nukes and kinetic impactors, but I do not want it to mess up other physics. It would be annoying if you cannot launch a rocket into orbit just because the CatIn messes with its physics.

My current idea is that the CatIn uses McGuffin magic to absorb energy into somewhere harmless (dark matter type II in my story, does not interact with anything even gravitationally but can be forced to interact momentarily). The CatIn only works between certain thresholds (for example between the energy output of the Fat Man and Tsar Bomba; it can be altered at will but that takes time) and has a limit to how much energy can be absorbed at once (so you cannot turn off the Sun).

For more clarity, imagine the blast-wave of the Fat Man at 50m distance, the energy per m<sup>3</sup> at that point is the threshold where CatIn stops working (this is just a random example the energy threshold can be altered to avoid problems). So if you detonated the Fat Man in a CatIn field it would for example have its energy absorbed so much that at 5m the CatIn already stops working, effectively making the Fat Man only 10% as powerful for anyone outside that radius but still almost 100% at point-blank range of the blast center.

The CatIn works as a facility, think a several acre large complex that protects a large part of the planet, with other complexes to create a field across the planet and have overlap in case of emergencies.

Would this work? Would this have effects on the planet? Would it need to work on a specific type of energy?

Comment: How exactly is such a CatIn deployed? Is it a mobile countermeasure, a field generated by a large facility, etc.? Otherwise, your CatIn is a handwave, as good as every other one, effectively draining energy and binding it without further harm.

Comment: "Would this work?" - with so much handwaving it will work if you will say it works. What parts should be considered handwavy? What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: Why 'nukes **and** kinetic impactors'? - that makes the question much harder to answer because these are very different animals. I suggest you limit your question to nukes only.

Comment: @JanDoggen actually "WMDs like nukes and kinetic impactors" potentially includes even more kinds...

Comment: @Darthdonut edited the question

Comment: @Molot if I have handwaved portable railguns and ask for a method on how to handle the recoil in a scientific way or the consequences of such a portable railgun being destroyed I dont want to hear "you handwaved something so handwave this as well", I want an answer. Same thing here, I handwave what is necessary and want to have as little extra hand-wave thank you very much.

Comment: @Demigan this does not answer my request for clarification: what part is handwaved and set in stone? And what part you want to check with us? Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @Molot ah ok.The method is handwaved, the question is what the effects would be on the world if such a CatIn existed. I'm unsure about what amount of energy it should use to be effective but not intrusive. The example given would mean that any kinetic interaction like an explosion would be at risk of getting affected by CatIn. This would also mean that a meteor of sufficient size would generate enough energy in front of it to have CatIn activate and basically increase it's drag with the air immensely before impacting. Which could limit maximum speeds of objects in atmosphere and cause trouble.

Comment: @Jandoggen I'm not sure why that would be a problem. Its not the nuclear interaction that's changed specifically but the effects of the nuclear interaction, IE massive release of energy has the energy absorbed into something reducing it's potential damage. But the CatIn could also inadvertently affect other things which aren't wanted. I want to Iron out cases where CatIn would mess up the rest of the world, for example it would probably be problematic if it affected continental movement and I would need a different explanation for CatIn's working.